# How to simplify conversion of nested object into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

This is my nested Object

```
var arr = [{
    "children": [{
        "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "A",
            "Image": "http://imgUrl"
        }],
        "Id": 2
        "Name": "B",
        "Image": "http://imgUrl"
    }],
    "Id":3,
    "Name": "C",
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}]
```

I wanted to convert the above to the following format

```
[{
    "Name": "C",
    "Id": 3,
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}, {
    "Name": "B",
    "Id": 2,
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}, {
    "Name": "A",
    "Id": 1,
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}]
```

I wrote below code to do this

```
    var newArr = []
    function getNestedObj(obj){

        if(obj.length){
            for ( var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
                var newObj = {};
                newObj.Name = obj[i].Name;
                newObj.Id = obj[i].Id;
                newObj.Image = obj[i].Image;
                newArr.push(newObj);

                if(obj[i].children.length !=0 ){
                    getNestedObj(obj[i].children)
                }
                else {
                    return newArr;
                }
        }
       }
    }
```

I want to simplify the above function? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Right now your code is working as expected? Or it is giving some error or unexpected result? If it is working, maybe you should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask

Comment: @ramya-selvaraj You're missing a comma after  "Id": 2. 
I can't edit it since an edit needs to be at least 6 characters.

Comment: @JasperZelf Thanks, i'll edit now : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try following

```js
let arr = [{"children":[{"children":[{"children":[],"Id":1,"Name":"A","Image":"http://imgUrl"}],"Id":2,"Name":"B","Image":"http://imgUrl"}],"Id":3,"Name":"C","Image":"http://imgUrl"}];

function fillWithChildren(a, r=[]) {
  a.forEach(({children, ...rest}) => {
    r.push(rest);
    if(children) fillWithChildren(children, r);
  });
  return r;
}
let result = fillWithChildren(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Superv, +1 for using `...rest` destruction from object. You could use `(a, r=[])` as optional parameter in order to avoid declaration of `result` and manually send it, and populating in the output in the given array (supplied from calling end). Instead you can declare optional with init, and return it.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee - Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I have incorporated it. Thanks!

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Thanks a lot for the solution. Can you please explain it? I'm not clear about ...rest??

Comment: @RamyaSelvaraj - It is an ES6 concept, and as the name suggest it means a collection of the remaining items. For details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 4):

This can be as simple as a recursive reduce.

```
arr.reduce (function spr (res, cur) {
    let obj = {...cur}
    let children = obj.children
    delete obj.children;
    return children.reduce (spr, res).concat ([{
        ...obj
    }])
}, [])
```

```js
let result = arr.reduce (function spr (res, cur) {
    let obj = {...cur}
    let children = obj.children;
    delete obj.children;
    return children.reduce (spr, res).concat ([{
       ...obj
    }])
}, [])

console.log (result)
```

```html
<script>
var arr = [{
    "children": [{
        "children": [{
            "children": [{
                "children": [],
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "A",
                "Image": "http://imgUrl"
            }],
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "A",
            "Image": "http://imgUrl"
        }],
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "B",
        "Image": "http://imgUrl"
    }],
    "Id":3,
    "Name": "C",
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}
, {
    "children": [{
        "children": [{
            "children": [],
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "A",
            "Image": "http://imgUrl"
        }],
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "B",
        "Image": "http://imgUrl"
    }],
    "Id":3,
    "Name": "C",
    "Image": "http://imgUrl"
}]
</script>
```

Comment: @StephanHovius Yes, it is? `spr` is the function used for `reduce`, look at the line `children.reduce (spr,...)`, that's a recursive call.

Comment: Yes, I missed it. If you use spread you could make it shorter using default with rest spread:  `arr.reduce(function spr(res, { children = [], ...rest }) {
    return children.reduce(spr, res).concat(rest);
  }, [])`

Answer (score 4):

Recursive Reduce:

```
const fillWithChildren = (a = []) =>
a.reduce(
    (result, { children, ...rest }) =>
        result
            .concat(rest)
            .concat(fillWithChildren(children)),
    [],
);
fillWithChildren(arr);
```

Comment: Edited my answer: set a default value, no ternary needed anymore.